# Hosting companies by AS Number

Tags: databases, server, web-hosting, bgp

Is there any website out the like bgp.he.net (Hurricane Electric) or ipv4info.com that has a database with all VPS/Dedicated Server comapnies filtered by AS Number?

I know that there are plenty of websites which have a database of predefined list of Hosting companies, but I need something independent like the above mentioned.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a security question. Also, I'm not sure where to migrate so that you can get an answer.